# setting spinner adapter without changing the item layout theme

Tags: java, android, spinner, android-arrayadapter

I fill up the spinner by this way

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, stringArray);
    modeSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

but these code changes the spinner item theme from

[image: default spinner style]

to

[image: spinner style after setting adapter]

so how can I set spinner adapter without changing the default theme

Comment: You mean the spacing is different, because I can't see any other difference. And how do you achieve the "from" spacing?

Comment: maybe yes. but is there a way to discard setadapter style changing issue?

Comment: What changing? did you use another adapter before that produced the "from" result?

Comment: the style I mean (the spacing in this case)

Comment: You posted an image of the desired spacing. How did you make this spacing happen and posted it? That's what I'm asking.

Comment: <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_mode"
                style="@style/setting"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct source code is:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, stringArray);
spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spin‌​ner_dropdown_item);
modeSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

You were missing the dropDown View layout.